# How does one change or remove the signature on the Windows 8 Metro email client?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-mail-app, email-signature

I don't like the automatic "Sent from Windows Mail" signature on messages sent with the Windows 8 Mail app. I tried looking into the settings panel for a signature option, but I couldn't find it. Am I missing out on it, or is there a way to change it by going into the registry or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When the app is open swipe from the right (outside of the screen) if you use a touch screen, or press 'Windows+I' to get to the settings
2. Select an account you would like to change the signature for.
3. Scroll down to the signature section, change it and close the settings pop-up.